# Compiling Red: Get Red/System Code

Tags: compilation, red

The video about Red and Red/System shows the compilation process in which Red is compiled to Red/System.

Youtube: https://youtu.be/-KqNO_sDqm4?t=27m12s

I know how to compile Red code with the -c option. Is there a way to output the Red/System code that is created during the compilation process?

Comment: Yes. That works. To get the code -c for compiling and verbositiy level 1 is needed:
`./red -c --red-only -v 1`

Please answer the question, then I can vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The README mentions `--red-only`](https://github.com/red/red), and says:

> *"Stop just after Red-level compilation. Use higher verbose level to see compiler output. (internal debugging purpose)"*

According to @jck this also requires -c for compiling and verbosity level 1:

```
./red -c --red-only -v 1
```